# parent child table to xml

Tags: sql, json, xml

I have the following table.

```
 id name parentid
 ----------------
 1  root null
 2  child A 1
 3  child B 2
 4  child C 1
```

Can someone point me in the right direction to export this into XML in either C# or SQL Server while supporting the hierarchy?

```
<node>root</node>
<children>
   <node>Child A</node>
     <children>
       <node>Child B</node>
     </children>
    <node>Child C</node>
  </children>
```

Comment: post what you want the output xml to look like, and exact table ddl

Comment: Please see comment above, thank you in advance.

Comment: suggest nesting children tag within the node element, otherwise the xml wont store this relationship, also should export the ids ( maybe as attributes )

Answer (score 0):

I ended up using this approach in c#.

http://w3facility.org/question/converting-datatable-into-json-tree-while-maintaining-parent-child-relationship/

Basically take the datatable, place into a hierarchical object, and then serialize to JSON.  Worked like a charm.

Comment: I know this thread is two years old, but it still comes up in Google searches and the link here now redirects to advertisements.